# The King's Decision

Tags: probability, self-study, categorical-data, joint-distribution

I was given the following problem for a homework assignment:

[image]

---

My solution to Part A gives the joint distribution:

$ P(\text{D} \vert \text{B, e} ) = \dfrac{P(\text{D,B} \vert \text{e} )}{P(\text{B} \vert \text{e})}$

$ \dfrac{P(\text{D=true, B=true} \vert \text{e=true} )}{P(\text{B=true} \vert \text{e=true})} = \dfrac{2}{10} = \boxed{.2}$

$ \dfrac{P(\text{D=true, B=false} \vert \text{e=true} )}{P(\text{B=false} \vert \text{e=true})} = \dfrac{16}{40} = \boxed{.4}$

$ \dfrac{P(\text{D=true, B=true} \vert \text{e=false} )}{P(\text{B=true} \vert \text{e=false})} = \dfrac{22}{40} = \boxed{.55}$

$ \dfrac{P(\text{D=true, B=false} \vert \text{e=false} )}{P(\text{B=false} \vert \text{e=false})} = \dfrac{8}{10} = \boxed{.8}$

---

My solution to Part B (assuming the king doesn't want to be deposed):

$ P(\text{D=false} \vert \text{B=true}) = .26$

$ P(\text{D=false} \vert \text{B=false}) = .26$

$\boxed{\text{The king's decision does not matter.}}$

$ \dfrac{P(\text{D=false, B=true} \vert \text{e=true} )}{P(\text{B=true} \vert \text{e=true})} = \dfrac{8}{10} = \boxed{.8}$

$ \dfrac{P(\text{D=false, B=false} \vert \text{e=true} )}{P(\text{B=false} \vert \text{e=true})} = \dfrac{24}{40} = \boxed{.6}$

$ \dfrac{P(\text{D=false, B=true} \vert \text{e=false} )}{P(\text{B=true} \vert \text{e=false})} = \dfrac{18}{40} = \boxed{.45}$

$ \dfrac{P(\text{D=false, B=false} \vert \text{e=false} )}{P(\text{B=false} \vert \text{e=false})} = \dfrac{2}{10} = \boxed{.2}$

$\boxed{\text{The king's charisma does affect the outcome.}}$

$\boxed{\text{As seen before, if the king's charisma is unknown his decision does not matter.}}$

---

For some reason I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong, so I wanted to confirm I was doing this right.  I heard of a way to check using inference by enumeration but I'm not fully sure how to do that either.